# PowerShell. Increase pull of remote sessions

Tags: powershell, session, remote-access

Hello StackOverlow community. How to increase pull of remote sessions in PowerShell? by default this value is set to 32 sessions. But It's not enough for me. How to increase this? And what is the maximal number of sessions that computer can proceed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understand your question correctly, but current WSMan settings can be seen using (provided you have administrator privileges):

```
dir WSMan:\localhost\shell
```

You can change default values through a command like this:

```
Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\shell\MaxShellsPerUser 100
```

Comment: Thank you. This is answer for my question.